# How to auto resize panes in tmux?

Tags: tmux

In Vim, with

```
 C-W =
```

the windows are auto resized to the same height.

In tmux, with

```
 :resize-pane -U 10
```

I can increment the height of tmux pane in 10.

How I can auto resize the panes to the same height?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I suggest resizing multiple panes with one of the five tmux presets:

```
C-b M-1             # vertical split, all panes same width
C-b M-2             # horizontal split, all panes same height
C-b M-3             # horizontal split, main pane on top,
                      other panes on bottom, vertically split, all same width
C-b M-4             # vertical split, main pane left,
                      other panes right, horizontally split, all same height
C-b M-5             # tile, new panes on bottom, same height before same width
```

`M` denotes the meta key, usually bound to <kbd>ALT</kbd>.

On Macs the meta key is usually <kbd>Esc</kbd>, as mentioned in the [comment below](https://superuser.com/questions/456775/tmux-auto-resize-panes/456799#comment534237_456799).

See the tmux manpage for more information.

Comment: M for 'meta', not 'magic' :) On Macs (not specified in the question, just for the benefit of any Mac users that might read this) it's usually the Escape key.

Comment: @chepner Now you made me taking all the magic from my reply... :(

Comment: +1 … I have a tmux compiled from source running on Linux and the default meta key is also Escape, rather than Alt.

Comment: useful to remap left option key to +Esc in iterm2 for macs. Prefs -> Profiles -> Keys -> Left option key acts as... setting.

Comment: on Ubuntu, with multiple tabs in a terminal open, ALT-n is sent to switch to tab #n

Answer (score 44):

`PREFIX Space` is shortcut for :next-layout

Comment: +1! What is this sorcery?!

Comment: Hit this by mistake today, after years of using tmux!!