# How to add horizontal pane above vertical panes in tmux?

Tags: tmux

I remember doing this before, but it was pretty tricky and I can't quite remember the combination of commands to get it to work. How can I turn my window with two vertical panes:

```
+------------+------------+
|            |            |
|            |            |
|            |            |
|            |            |
|            |            |
|            |            |
|            |            |
|            |            |
|            |            |
|            |            |
|            |            |
|            |            |
|            |            |
|            |            |
|            |            |
+------------+------------+
```

Into a window with one horizontal pane and two vertical panes in an orientation like so:

```
+-------------------------+
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
+------------+------------+
|            |            |
|            |            |
|            |            |
|            |            |
|            |            |
|            |            |
|            |            |
+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I may have figured this out based off of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/456775/tmux-auto-resize-panes) question. This specific layout is the third in [speakr's answer](https://superuser.com/a/456799/137423) (`C-b M-3`). Last time I did it in a much stranger way.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply split one of your panels and rotate between layouts with "C-b Space". For some reason "C-b M-3" is not working properly on my computer.